# Video quality issue with OpenTok library

Tags: android, opentok

I am using OpenTok to implement video chat on Android.

I start the video chat session on my android app which has tokbox implementation. The bandwidth is around 50 - 100KB/s. Video quality received on the other app is not great.

We also have a web-based app. When I open that on my browser on the android phone, the quality is much better with the same bandwidth as above. I need some help to improve the video quality on the native android app.

I am using Android OS Oreo and Chrome browser. 
My opentok version is: `opentok-android-sdk:2.13.0`

Comment: TokBox Developer Evangelist here.

Could you please see if you're having the same issue with `opentok-android-sdk:2.15.0`?

Comment: Yeah I tried again after upgrading to 2.15.0. The video quality on the receiver side is still not that good. I am using High Resolution and 30 fps, but on the server side the resolution is majorly at 540x960. Why is that @Manik

Comment: @Manik Can you please respond

Comment: could you please email support@tokbox.com? They should be able help you diagnose the quality issues. Please also share the sessionId with them.